# ¿Por qué Docker ignora los cambios que hago en /etc/hosts?

Tags: docker

Estoy teniendo problemas al intentar añadir un host predeterminado a una imagen de Docker. Tengo mi simple archivo`Dockerfile` con esto:

```
FROM alpine

RUN echo "172.17.0.1 test.docker" >> /etc/hosts
```

Construyo la imagen ejecutando

```
docker build -t example -f Dockerfile .
```

Al ejecutar el contenedor y revisar el archivo /etc/hosts nunca encuentro el host que añadí cuando construí la imagen. Intenté usar otro SO diferente a Alpine y sigo obteniendo lo mismo. ¿Por qué sucede esto y de qué forma puedo lograrlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker no te permitira hacer eso por ser un archivo del sistema, para hacer lo que quieres usa la opcion --add-host="test.docker:172.17.0.1"

que es parte de las network options al lanzar el contenedor

para mas informacion mira https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings

Espero te sea de ayuda saludos

Comment: Excelente, funciona. ¡Gracias y bienvenido a SO.es!